# Short videos on evolutionary biology

Tags: evolution

## What I am looking for

I'm considering to eventually start my teaching sessions with **short emotional, awe-inspiring or exciting videos** that are somehow related to evolutionary biology incl. diversity of life, history of evolution on earth, specific evolutionary processes (sexual conflict, evolution of ageing, evolution of mutation rate, speciation rate, ...), diversity in mating systems, major transitions, etc...

3-minute long movies would be perfect. 15 minutes would be too long. The videos should be easily accessible for Bachelor students having little background in evolutionary biology.

## Examples

[Asap Science video about the evolutionary history of life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2_6cqa2cP4) would be a good fit.

The beginning of [We are all related by vsauce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhtgINeaJWg) would be a good fit.

This [video from SciShow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROwKq3kxPEA) is typically too long

[This video on the evolution of human face](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rfn9hYCSYj0) would do but I am not quite sure how exact it is and it feels a little weird that the end product is a white male!

It'd be great if not all suggestions were about recent human history or about dinosaurs :)

*Do you have any suggestions?*

Comment: This question might very well be off-topic here. Let me know and I'll delete it. Advice on where to ask such questions would be very welcome.

Comment: The question is fine and will likely produce a good resource for the community.

Comment: Upvoted! Normally those kinds of questions get asked when an SE communitiy starts out so I would say it is high time :-)

Comment: @Remi.b I'm curious, is there anything _wrong_ with your first example that you say is a good fit?

Comment: @Insane. No, it is a good fit but I am hoping to have several such good fits.

Comment: I think you should show your students a video by a creationist on why evolution is not true. That would certainly inspire them to appreciate the logic of evolution ;)

Comment: I lead a workshop on protein packing that opened with this [video of the inner workings of the cell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHeTQLNFTgU) by Biovisions at Harvard. I narrated what is happening whilst the video was playing (I sometimes found it awkward when lecturers and teachers just watched the video too!). It's off topic at first glance, but It could set the tone for the complexity of life at a molecular level, and how evolution acts at a molecular level.

Comment: @biogirl Don't be so sure that intelligent design videos can't be compelling and inspiring. [This clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3KxU63gcF4) is one of the prettiest and most informative ATP synthase videos available and it argues ***for*** intelligent design.

Comment: @James Oh you are right. But I think you can use that video in a productive way. Show it to "inspire" students and then prick the balloon by carefully explaining why the argument is not acceptable to biologists even if it is so seductive.

Comment: I suggest the [Stated Clearly](https://www.youtube.com/user/sciencestatedclearly) channel, but the videos are longer than 3 minutes

Comment: I find it discouraging that nobody else realizes that the subjectivity of this question (what you consider exciting is not necessary what I consider exciting) renders it off topic. Furthermore I think it is bad to try to appeal to the emotions rather than the intellect. That is the approach of the irrationalists. Evolution is yesterday's scientific news. Ignore the flat earthers and move on.

Answer (score 5):

I saw this HHMI video today. It is called [The Animated Life of A.R. Wallace](http://www.hhmi.org/biointeractive/animated-life-ar-wallace), and it discusses the contributions that Alfred R. Wallace made to evolutionary theory. It is a little long for your stated time of 3-minutes. but it talks about how in fits of malaria he came up with his ideas on evolution.

HHMI also has a whole series of videos and modules on [Evolution](http://www.hhmi.org/biointeractive/evolution-collection), though Wallace's came to mind as it showed his ambition and desire to solve the problem, even though he had not received formal training in the sciences.

Comment: Nice video. It is nice also to bring some fame to Wallace and not only to Darwin. I'm looking at the other videos on the website. +1

Answer (score 3):

It is not really a video but it is a real life simulation in the browser about vehicles that evolve to master a race track. I project it onto the screen while I introduce genetic algorithms in my data science classes. I then ask people to identify key features of the evolutionary process and we talk about it while the "cars" are still evolving:
http://boxcar2d.com/

People told me that this is really motivating. After that we start programming our first genetic algorithm.

This is a video that I sometimes show additionally (5 min. about robots in an artificial world learning to walk):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgaEE27nsQw

Comment: Not quite what I expected but it is nice. I particularly appreciate the evolving car simulator. What population size, type of terrain and mutation rate do you recommend to maximize the speed of improvement? Can you maybe say a word about how you coded the information about the car and how to interpret a mutation? Would be great to have a snapshot of the parent population on the side to understand that we have a population and not just a series of random individuals. +1

Comment: @Remi.b: Thank you, I appreciate your feedback. I have to run now but I will answer your questions later!

Answer (score 2):

https://youtu.be/hOfRN0KihOU Sorry, this video is not short, but perfect. From Kurzgesagt chanel youtube

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I agree Kurzgesagt (a.k.a. In a nutshell) is a great channel. The video is a bit long though (as you said). It is also a little too introductory and too general and not very "emotional, awe-inspiring or exciting".

Answer (score 2):

Here are a bunch of fun videos about evolution! They might not be very educative at first sight but they might still bring more than just a laugh to students.

**MinuteEarth videos**

The youtube channel [**MinuteEarth**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeiYXex_fwgYDonaTcSIk6w) has plenty of evolution related videos of about 2-6 minutes each. Look for example at

- [Males vs. Females: Sexual Conflict](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMCtE2-YsLc)
- [Why Do Animals Eat Their Babies?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xVgAULDwNE)
- [Do We Have to Get Old and Die?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc_VENHxLg0)
- [Are We Really 99% Chimp?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbY122CSC5w)
- [Why are Males often More Physically Aggressive?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USR-yHJAEGE)
- [Epigenetics: Why Inheritance Is Weirder Than We Thought](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvB0q3mg4sQ)

**PBS Eons**

[PBS Eons](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzR-rom72PHN9Zg7RML9EbA/featured) have a lot of cool videos on the history of life on earth. Videos might be a bit long for your needs though, around 5-10 minutes long on average.

**MaxBird feat Jamie**

- [Les dinosaures ont disparu ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcejX_11UUk) in 7'51'' (in french)

**How is evolution often misrepresented**

- [South Park - Mr. Garrison's Evolution Theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BL9S-TUikfg) in 51''

and of course

- [Simpsons - Homer's evolution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci9jfMvoLb4) in 1'29''

One can also just type `Evolution` on google Image to get only this misleading and anthropocentric view of representation of evolution

[image]

Why Pokemon evolution is not like evolution in nature

- [Dirty Biology - Darwin chez les Pokemon (in french)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcKfWW7sAMk)

---

**Song**

- [Evo-Devo A capella on Despacito](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXLqDGL1FSg) by acapellascience.

---

**Creationist argument** (although this is not really the way the OP wants to go to)

- [Simpsons - Missing link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydqReeTV_vk) (start at 1'14'' to 2'10)

In the category 'Response to creationist argument' it is easy to find funny videos just by showing burlesque creationist argument such as

- [Ray Comfort - banana proves God](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTOla3TyfqQ) (from 1'12'' to 2'20 although the whole video is pretty funny). The video mixes up questions of believing in God and of evolution which I don't mean to do myself and could (rightly) be taken as offensive by students so be careful.

Answer (score 2):

BBC and other CG animation programs about Ediacaran life, trilobites, other old life forms, are very engaging to see. There are a lot of CG progams bringing to life ediacaran seas. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znO8q5Ht17g

David Attenboroughs CG animation of the chinese microraptor, where it steps out of it's fossil and flies around the room. 
microraptor chasing other flying reptile:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fyxUxGdrns

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmcqnAWKLJQ

Comment: I like the David Attenboroughs link! Thanks +1. Note that the last link on 'Microraptor' is in french. Don't remove it but you should probably highlight it in your answer and explain what it is.

Comment: sry didn't have time to find the original english version.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fyxUxGdrns here it is, first result for "microraptor chase"... it's narrated by john hurt, the recently defunct actor of midnight expess and the storyteller series.

Answer (score 0):

This Evo-Devo music video from A Capella Science is very good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydqReeTV_vk&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thank you! The link is already present in my answer though.